# Reading in files from a command line in C

Tags: c, command-line, file-io, file-read

so i'm pretty new to C and i've been trying to figure out how to read a text file in for reading as in the line below.

```
./atc < example_input_001.txt
```

I'm trying to print the lines out one by one but I don't know how to access the file.

So far I've just been reading in the file like this but that's only because I know the file name, I need the program to work for any file given in the command line.

```
FILE *open_ADSB_file = fopen("example_input_001.txt", "r");

    if (open_ADSB_file == NULL) {
        printf("No valid file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Don't read files. Go read about (and then read from) `stdin`, the standard input `FILE *` that most every executable has available... `fgets( buf, bufSize, stdin );` and `fread( buf, size, cnt, stdin );`

Comment: Programs that get (the most of) their input from `stdin` and output (mostly) to `stdout` are called "_filters_". Eg: "cat file1 file2 | grep foo | sort > myList.txt". In this example, both grep and sort are acting as 'filters'...

Comment: *"how to read a text file in"* A great place to start learning about `C` programming. Reading files (binary or text) is a key skill and good to understand. This will be key in building useful programs (along with a thousand other things (sorry!) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. What you are using is called `stdin`. You can access `stdin` just like a file. You should replace your `fopen` call with something more like `freopen(NULL, "r", stdin)`.

[`freopen()` reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/)

Comment: Sweet, that worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: @LucaAgius If the answer worked, don't forget to mark it as accepted.